# SQL Server 2008 vs 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Locally, when I open SQL Server Management Studio 2012 I connect to my databases by server name of `{MyPCName}`.

Now and then, always changing after a machine shutdown, this fails. If I change the server name to `{MyPCName}/SQLExpress`.

It looks as though I have two versions of SQL Server installed. 2010, and 2011.

Looking at the program logs, yesterday for example, when I could logon using `{MyPCName}` the SQL Server logs seem to have been updating the logs in the folder `MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER`. Today the logs seem to be updating the logs in the folder `MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS`.

Looking in my installed programs list I appear to have SQL Server 2008 and 2012 installed.

Is there a way to, either, be able to select which you connect to / remove version 2010?

These are all Express versions by the way in case it makes any difference. ;-)

Comment: `2010` and `2011` don't exist. The `MSSQL10` and `MSSQL11` are version numbers for 2008 and 2012 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are not running two express versions, unless you ended up renaming one instance during installation. The SQL11 (SQ Server 2012) installation has a default name of `MSSQLSERVER`. Express edition typically names itself `SQLEXPRESS`, as you saw in the 2008 version.

This also explains why you can connect using nothing more than the local host name. If you want to connect to a non-default named instance, you have to add the instance name (I.e. `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`).

Using SQL Server Setup, you can uninstall one of the versions completely.

Prior to doing so, make sure you take a backup of your system databases (master, model, and msdb) in case you end up needing anything in them. I'd also advise you to detach whatever user databases you still need from the old instance, and then attaching them to the new instance.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So if I didn't rename the instance during installation, I should be able to connect to the 2012 version by doing localhost\MSSQLSERVER? This doesn't seem to work at the moment.

I think I'm fine to uninstall 2008, as I can't see a reason why I need both. After doing this should I be able to connect to 2012 again using either {MyPCName} / localhost / {localhost/MSSQLSERVER} / {MyPCName/MSSQLSERVER}?

If on the off chance I did rename my 2012 instance, is there a way to find out what I changed it to?

Comment: Actually, you cannot have two instances with the same name. So if you had an SQLEXPRESS already, and then tried creating a new one, it'd have thrown an error.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Configuration Manager to see what instances you are running. The names can also be seen in the Services list.

Comment: As for aliases for your localhost, check this for different options:

http://mssqlforum.com/threads/connecting-to-a-local-sql-instance.39/#post-63

Disclosure: That's my site.

Comment: Cheers Schmitz. Interesting stuff.


I uninstalled SQL Server 2008, and everything seems to be back to normal now, so thanks to everyone for their replies and help.